Can't understand this C syntax. Designated initialization of an array of structs?
Trying to learn the nuances of C, though I was doing well until I found this:
#define SOKOL_IMPL
#define SOKOL_GLES3
#include "sokol_gfx.h"
#include "sokol_log.h"
#include "emsc.h"

static struct {
    sg_pipeline pip;
    sg_bindings bind;
    sg_pass_action pass_action;
} state = {
    .pass_action.colors[0] = { .load_action = SG_LOADACTION_CLEAR, .clear_value = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }
};

It's sample code from Sokol library: https://github.com/floooh/sokol-samples/blob/master/html5/triangle-emsc.c
I get that the first struct declaration also declares a variable "state", then I think this new variable is assigned to whatever is after "=" using a "designated init". What I don't understand is what .pass_action.colors[0] is.
I thought "colors" is a field inside pass_action, which in turn makes pass action a struct and colors should be an array. But, "colors" assignment uses designated inits idiomatic to structs again.
So, maybe .colors[0] is a field of .pass_action and also an array of structs, which have two fields: "load_action" and "clear_value". Is that correct? I need to be sure before making progress.
"Designated Inits": https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html
UPDATE: sg_pass_action is declared here and "colors" type is defined a few lines above https://github.com/floooh/sokol/blob/6f8121e6aa523b0c0a3e9d7212073bab9a885e15/sokol_gfx.h#L2542
This has been pointed out to me elsewhere on reddit and clears everything up (I think). "colors" is an array of type "sg_color_attachment_action" which itself is a struct. And of size "SG_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS".

I think your final analysis in the penultimate paragraph is basically correct. Of course the structures in the colors[] array might have more than two fields, but you only initialise two of them.

Just guessing here, but sq_pass_action is likely a structure, containing a member named colors which is an array of structures. Why not simple check the source and header files?

The syntax intialises specific members.

The syntax initializes specific members to specific values and all other members to 0, recursively if needed.

Thank you all : )
I checked the headers by myself, but wasn't sure still, since I'm just learning this. It's very different from what I'm used to.
I think it is confirmed tho, someone (on reddit) pointed out a relevant fragment in sokol_gfx.h where "colors" is declared as an array of another type, which is a struct. (I think). I might update the question later.

I looked at the project sokol and it appears to be a cross-platform wrapper around OpenGL, DirectX, and several other graphics frameworks.  See https://github.com/floooh/sokol/blob/master/sokol_gfx.h, starting at line 544.  After I looked at some of the documentation surrounding sg_pass_action I was reminded of what needs to be set up for a render pass in Vulkan.
